# SQL: Show records where calculated field is MAX value

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

In the example below, I use code to create the "total" column. I only want to retain the record for EACH ID that is has the highest total. So record 3 and 4 should be the only results in the output table.

```
SELECT ID, ObsPer, col1, col2, col3, SUM(col1,col2,col3) AS total
FROM mytable
```

Since "total" is a calculated field, how do I add a command that only brings back the highest "total" value for each "ID".

*I'm a novice with this stuff, so please excuse me if I'm not explaining myself well enough!*

| ID | ObsPer | col1 | col2 | col3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201903 01 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | 201903 02 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 15 |
| 1 | 201903 03 | 6 | 4 | 9 | 19 |
| 2 | 201904 01 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 17 |
| 2 | 201904 02 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 201904 03 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 7 |

I thought it could be a WHERE or HAVING command but the one's I've tried always error out.

**Expected Result**

| ID | ObsPer | col1 | col2 | col3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201903 03 | 6 | 4 | 9 | 19 |
| 2 | 201904 01 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 17 |

Comment: Your use of `SUM()` is confusing.  You don't have an aggregation query and it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT ID, ObsPer, col1, col2, col3, 
             (col1 + col2 + col3) AS total,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col1 + col2 + col3 DESC) as seqnum
      FROM mytable
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```